# Configuring Git trigger for Jenkins? (Using TFS2017)

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, tfs, triggers

The scenario:

1. TFS2017 Team Project
2. 150-200 Git repositories
3. Each repository has 10-30 branches

We're looking to incorporate Jenkins into our workflow to help with TFS builds and external deployments & tests. We need a Jenkins job to trigger on a Git code push, simple enough. There needs to be check-in information passed into the job, couldn't care if it's in the form of parameters or something like a HTTP POST payload, that includes basic information like branch name, repository name/url, etc. Since we're using 1 Jenkins scripted pipeline for all repositories and branches, we do not want to check in 1 single Jenkinsfile into 300+ branches that requires updating every branch when we need to perform a change to the pipeline.

Our attempts:

1. TFS Jenkins Service Hook to Jenkins Pipeline project: Does not pass in dynamic parameters (branch/repo name) and cannot retrieve payload into the pipeline script.
2. TFS Jenkins Service Hook to Jenkins Multibranch project (with the help of "Pipeline: Multibranch with default" plugin): In the TFS Service Hook, when using "Trigger generic build" we must specify the Multibranch/repobranch job name individually per Service Hook, or if using "Trigger Git build" option it triggers all Multibranch branches' builds simultaneously.
3. TFS Jenkins Service Hook to Jenkins Multi-Configuration project: Cannot specify a Jenkinsfile to be ran by the Jenkins project.
4. TFS Generic Web Hook to any Jenkins project: Crumbs error rules this possibility out.

Please let me know if there's something we missed with the attempts above or entirely different approach to this.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why Jenkins instead of the out-of-the-box build/release capabilities?

Comment: Considered TFS Build to call a simple powershell to invoke the Jenkins build? Gives you maximum availability to variables and full control over the datashape when calling Jenkins.

Comment: Also wondering what Jenkins offers you over TFS Buikd, though I suspect it's the Jenkinsfile, Build Config as Code. Consider upgrading to TFS 2018 for YAML support in TFS.

Comment: For such a big project I would go with Job DSL plugin. I'm having a lot of success with it and makes maintenance really easy. You can do stuff like download all the branches from git repo and create a job for each branch.

Comment: I would personally love to use built-in TFS Build which simply enough triggers on code push and can execute a Jenkins build on successful build completion, but alas (against my will) that is not an option for independent reasons.

Comment: We cannot use a build definition that only calls a PowerShell or executes a Jenkins build because we have over a hundred repositories and TFS build definitions only allow to specify one repository per build definition. Although this option would also work but look "ugly", this proposed solution was abruptly denied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone comes across the same issue, the answer/resolution:

For now we will be disabling CSRF in Jenkins and going with #4 above. Using Generic Web Hook Plugin we can specify variables that use JSONPaths from the incoming payload of the Generic Web Hook sent by TFS.

Longer term when this project is fleshed out we will write our own service to listen for the TFS Generic Web Hook request and then get a crumb followed by sending a formal HTTP Post to the Generic Web Hook Plugins default url it listens to (with Jenkins' CSRF enabled).